# Getting Fatal Error from Cron php script but runs 100% in browser

Tags: php, cron, dataflow

I have a custom dataflow export script that when i run via the browser it works 100% no issue.
But soon as i add it to a cron i get a fatal error in my email report

"Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /home/#######/public_html/custom_scripts/dataflow_scheduled_export.php on line 87"

Struggling to work out why it runs fine from browser but not via cron job???

Help needed please

[image: Script]

Comment: try giving full path names in the script. /home/#######/public_html/app/Mage.php

Comment: Please pastebin or gist your cron script.

Comment: Command line php interpreter may run with a different php.ini file than Apache DSO module php interpreter as well so it also may have memory_limit issues once you get the path figured out.

Comment: Answer from Kalpesh i have tried this already it makes no difference i still get same error, but thank you. Reply to Reid Blomquist this is my current cron script you asked for; we have tried several iterations with my host provider. But i get the same error with all versions we have tried to date. They indicate it is a script error but i know people using it and it works. /usr/local/php54/bin/php-cli /home/#######/public_html/custom_scripts/dataflow_scheduled_export.php && echo test

Comment: Fiasco sorry you have lost me a little i do not understand what you mean (newbie). But this db for this install only has 50 products so we have no time out issue i believe. When run via browser it only takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

When you running this script via cron - first you must change directory to script directory, so yoou must do cd /home/#######/public_html/custom_scripts/ first and then run script
so cron command must look something like

```
cd /home/#######/public_html/custom_scripts/; php dataflow_scheduled_export.php
```

I think

Comment: please vote the unswer as it's right ;)

Comment: It wont let me !!!!!!